# Why is an image formed where the direction of incident ray meets?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

[image]Why is an image formed where the direction of incident ray meets?For example:If a light ray is incident on a plane mirror , the ray will partly reflect and refract.Now the position where the direction of incident ray meets and a ray perpendicular to the plane mirror is where the image is formed.Why is it like that?Since the back side is polished.How does that happen we are still able to see. and please share if there is any proof or mathematical derivation for the image formation with the direction of incident ray.If you wish to close this question , please let know how this question is off-topic.

Comment: You can leave out the complication of refraction by constructing your mirror from a polished thick slab of a metal (Aluminum or such).

Comment: But how can you prove that the direction of incident but not the ray itself , will form an image at that point.If you could give a proof , it would be very helpful

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What do you mean by "direction of incident"? And which ray do you mean in "... ray itself ..."?

Comment: Ok sir.I have added a image to the question. The red dotted line is the - "Direction of incident ray".Even though there is a plane mirror and the back side is polished.What is the geomretical or mathematical proof that image will be formed at X?.Thank you

Comment: Forget about the ray itself.I don't have that image

Answer (score 1):

When the light rays reach our eyes (as you've depicted in your diagram) our brain doesn't know whether those light rays are being reflected off from a mirror, or is there a real object present behind that mirror. This is because the light rays from any real object and the reflected light rays **cannot be distinguished** because both of them are **identical**. Thus your brain is *tricked* into thinking that there is a *real object behind the mirror*, whereas in reality, there isn't.

Answer (score -1):

When the incident rays leave that point, it is no different to the rays that would have left the object if it were there.  Having passed through the focus, it is no different to having risen from the object itself.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.Can you explain more please?Thank you

Comment: I am not understanding how do you mean to prove the answer to  my questioon

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any fundamental proof or reason behind that. It's like asking why does light reflect at all? The point I am trying to make is that it's not for us to choose. We know light reflects and bends and we can't do otherwise. The much we can do is study these natural phenomena that light exhibits and be able to describe and predict their properties on a macroscopic scale. QM may have a reason for it though, but well...who knows?? So, if we observe that light forms image at the **point where the reflected or refracted rays appear to converge or diverge from,** then all we can do is accept this basic truth and study the details.